# uninitialized constant Users ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an app that I am working on, and there appear to be two key problems: due to a problem undetectable by me, the webapp I am working on returns the error "uninitialized constant Users" and the error "uninitiallized constant SubmitController." The [code for the webapp is here](https://github.com/swarage/pilotphilly2013). I have tried renaming multiple, possibly violating variables, and attempted to rid the app of the errors. However, I have not been sucessful. The code where the errors most likely originate are from app/views/users/show.html.erb, app/views/users/show.html.erb, app/controllers/user/submit.html.erb, app.controllers/user/submit_controller.rb, app/models/Submit.rb, app/models/user.rb, app/controllers/users_controller.rb, config/routes.rb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have error because you don't have SubmitsContoller. Also you need to move app/controller/users/submit.erb to `views` folder. And one more rename file Submit.rb to submit.rb.
And to make it works create submit_controller.rb in controller folder.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I also have the same problem with User. Is there a way around that as well?

Comment: User must works. It's important to see logs. For example you can start rails console - `rails c`, and see that User.count works.

Comment: I would recommend to start from the beginning and now place controllers in controller views, views in views and use valid names for your files.